# Upgrade 8.3.7 to 8.4.5

Tags: 8, upgrading

This is going to sound really weird, but I just upgraded from 8.3.7 to 8.4.5 and now whenever I make a template change and rebuild cache, whatever that element was, disappears.

I edited a page template and rebuilt cache and the page is completely blank now. When turning on Twig debug, it shows that the template is being rendered, but there is no output.

I know that 8.3.x => 8.4.x has a Symfony upgrade from 2.8 to 3.2. I assume the issue is being caused by this. I also noticed that Twig went from 1.25 to 1.35.

As a side note, even reverting the template back to the original state and rebuilding cache, the elements/pages do not come back either.

Has anyone else come across this issue? Any suggestions? Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you seeing any php/apache errors? Did you update via composer's `--with-dependencies`?

Comment: Ya, I have updated everything. No errors. The page renders fine, but the templates don't output anything.

Comment: Are you using composer-project or just a plain drupal download? I'd try to narrow it down, e.g. update composer.json to force twig back to 1.25 to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Twig 1.25 is not compatible with the new HttpKernal. I tried that already unfortunately.